# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` supplied to `Redirect`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

My app.js looks like this :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthenticationLayout} />
        <Route path="/dash" component={DashboardLayout} />

        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
          <Redirect to={AuthenticationLayout} />
        )}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Cant't undersatnd what's the problem

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: why you are using render here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `to` prop in Redirect accepts either a string, which is the route you want to navigate to, or an object which can contain properties like `pathname`, `state`, etc.

Ex (from the docs) :

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```

So, when you are trying to pass a component to the prop `to`, you get an error.

Correct implementation is:

```
<Redirect to="/auth" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect is a navigate to a new location, `to` accept the URL to redirect to,
you can write like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
      <Redirect to="/auth" />
    )}/>
```